# Why is $\langle p,q \rangle = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

First of all, sorry for opening a new question about it, but I'm curious to understand:

John Hughes claims that $\langle p,q \rangle =0$ (in the end of his answer)

Why is it true?

[Prove that there is a unique inner product on V](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1092181/188391)

Comment: what are $p$ and $q$ ? the chip 'n' dale ?

Comment: Why down-voting? It's a legitimate question

Comment: of course it is, but not like this ! You have to define every thing ! like this is not incomprehensible !

Comment: It is all mentioned in the link I added. Should I copy-paste the whole question?

Comment: This question really belongs in a comment. I would delete this question.

Comment: @AlonAlon: I'm guessing this question has been downvoted because you waited less than $40$ minutes for John Hughes to reply to your comment before asking a new question.

Comment: yes, it would be better :-)

Comment: You all right guys, if I could I'd downvote my own question :D

Comment: I agree with @copper.hat.  I'm closing as a duplicate of the other question; this entire thread belongs in the comments there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p \in W_1, q \in W_2$, then write $p = p_1 + 0, q = 0 + q_2$ so $\langle p, q \rangle = \langle p_1,0\rangle_1 + \langle 0,q_2\rangle_2 = 0$.

Comment: Oh right right... I guess my head stopped functioning :)